# Check if variable of type Enum is in a set of Enums

Tags: python, enums, comparison, membership

According to the documentation of Enums in Python, comparison primarily refer to the `is` operator, due to Enums being a singleton. However, if one would check if an Enum is in a set of Enums, is it then perfectly fine to use the `in` operator? It seems to work as expected, but my knowledge comes short here if there are any caveats that must be taken.

The following code should suffice as an illustrative example:

```
from enum import auto, StrEnum


class MyEnum(StrEnum):
    STR1 = auto()
    STR2 = auto()
    STRN = auto()


def main():

    foo = MyEnum.STR1

    if foo in {MyEnum.STR1, MyEnum.STR2}: # is this okay?
        print("foo")

    if foo is MyEnum.STR1 or foo is MyEnum.STR2: # the alternative following the documentation
        print("foo")

main()
```

I have looked up the documentation, and found the `is` operator to be best practice, as well as related questions here on StackOverflow. Moreover, I have experimented with examples my self, which seems to work as expected. Nevertheless, I did not succeed finding an answer to my exact question.

Any insight to whether if it is okay, and also, what the actual difference might be at a lower level is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if `a is b`, then `a == b`. This is the reflexive property of equality: an object should equal to itself.

Generally, if `b` is an iterable and `a in b`, then `any(value == a for value in b)`. If `a` is contained in `b`, then `b` must have at least one element that is equal to `a`.

Therefore, you can assume

```py
foo is MyEnum.STR1 or foo is MyEnum.STR2
```

is equivalent to

```py
foo == MyEnum.STR1 or foo == MyEnum.STR2
```

which is equivalent to

```
foo in {MyEnum.STR1, MyEnum.STR2}
```

Using them interchangeably is safe, since both set and enums are built-in types and do not have any special logic for equality or membership.

Of course checking using `is` is a good practice, but readability of your code is a better practice. If you need to compare with five enum values, which code is more readable?

```py
if foo in {MyEnum.STR1, MyEnum.STR2, MyEnum.STR3, MyEnum.STR4, MyEnum.STR5}:
    pass

if foo is MyEnum.STR1 or foo is MyEnum.STR2 or foo is MyEnum.STR3 or foo is MyEnum.STR4 or foo is MyEnum.STR5:
    pass
```

Comment: Your last point regarding readability was my exact reason for this question. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use `is` instead of `==` is style and intent:

- `==` tells you if two objects are equal to each other
- `is` will tell you if the two objects are actually the same object

When creating your own objects via `class`, if you do not specify an `__eq__` method, the default `__eq__` uses `is`.

```
some_obj in some_container
```

is basically shorthand for

```
for obj in some_container:
    if obj is some_obj or obj == some_obj:
        return True
else:
    return False
```